# Magento 1.9 custom module with custom database table not saving

Tags: magento, model, magento-1.9

I have developed a custom module that also has a custom database table.
However, I cannot insert records since I am presented with the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function beginTransaction() on boolean in /httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php on line 6105
```

Here is the code that I am trying:

```
$data = array(
          'voucher'     => 'voucher',
          'customer_name' => 'customer_name',
          'order'           => 'order',
          'value'           => 'value',
          'status'      => 1,
          'date'            => '',
        );
$model = Mage::getModel('antikatavoles/antikatavoles')->setData($data);
```

And this is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>

<modules>
    <ID_Antikatavoles>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </ID_Antikatavoles>
</modules>

<frontend>
    <routers>
        <antikatavoles>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>ID_Antikatavoles</module>
                <frontName>antikatavoles</frontName>
            </args>
        </antikatavoles>
    </routers>
</frontend>  
<global>
    <models>
        <antikatavoles>
            <class>ID_Antikatavoles_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>antikatavoles_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </antikatavoles>
        <antikatavoles_mysql4>
            <class>ID_Antikatavoles_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <antikatavoles>
                    <table>antikatavoles</table>
                </antikatavoles>
            </entities>
        </antikatavoles_mysql4>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <antikatavoles_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>ID_Antikatavoles</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </antikatavoles_setup>
        <antikatavoles_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </antikatavoles_write>
        <antikatavoles_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </antikatavoles_read>
    </resources>
    <helpers>
        <antikatavoles>
            <class>ID_Antikatavoles_Helper</class>
        </antikatavoles>
    </helpers>
</global>

</config>
```

Can anyone help me figure this one out?

thanks!

EDIT:

My model and resource model:

```
class ID_Antikatavoles_Model_Antikatavoles extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('antikatavoles/antikatavoles');
    }
}

class ID_Antikatavoles_Model_Mysql4_Antikatavoles extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {  
        $this->_init('antikatavoles/antikatavoles', 'antikatavoles_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Is magento running in compilation mode? Please try after disabling compilation mode. This will show more accurate error message.

Comment: Now the error is `Fatal error: Call to a member function beginTransaction() on boolean in /var/www/vhosts/fifthelement.gr/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php on line 313`

Comment: Also, can you please share the contents of your custom model and the resource model for it?

Comment: Your model is unable to get its resource model. Please check class name of resource model or you can debug $this->_resourceName in method _getResource() in Abstract.‌​php file.

Comment: I added the code for model/resource model to the main post.